# JavaScript heap out of memory while exporting with SheetJS[cant increase memory]

Tags: node.js, mongoose, sheetjs

I am exporting 100k userdata from mongodb and while processing those data I create object and add to array. In that process, the server throws out of memory erray. Any effiecient solution to export those files using mongoose and sheetjs??

Comment: (a) Don't load all of the data from MongoDB at once (see: mongoose pagination) (b) See if you can stream directly to disk with SheetJS.

Comment: (a) can't do pagination as my manger wants those 90k records in csv on one click. (b) I tried stream but still could not find the way to address my problem.

Comment: I mean pagination within your request. Eg. get 1000 users, write them to the file, get the next users, write them to the file, ...